# How to command a repo to checkout a branch while in an irrelevant folder?

Tags: git, github, git-branch

Imagine this folder structure:

```
foo/
  bar/.git # branch=master
  baz/.git # branch=test
```

Now imagine that my current path is `foo/bar`, but without switching directories, I would like to write a command that tells `baz` to checkout the branch `master` (already stored locally). In an ideal world, this would look something like:

```
[foo/bar]$ git --use-path=../baz checkout master
[foo/bar]$
```

I am trying to avoid doing:

```
[foo/bar]$ cd ../baz
[foo/baz]$ git checkout master
[foo/baz]$ cd ../bar
[foo/bar]$
```

I would also prefer something built into git, and would like to avoid concatenating commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-C` switch for that. From the manual:

> `-C <path>`
>
> Run as if git was started in `<path>` instead of the current working directory. When multiple `-C`  options are given, each subsequent non-absolute `-C <path>` is interpreted relative to the preceding `-C <path>`.

This feature was added in Git 1.8.5.

Comment: Alternative solution I think would be to use sub shell commands which I just learned about per this question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13802/execute-a-specific-command-in-a-given-directory-without-cding-to-it

Comment: Yes, that works fine too. Sometimes `pushd`/`popd` come in handy too. Or shell functions. Lots of alternatives.